# cannot find symbol in android studio while connecting to firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-activity, firebase-authentication

When I am trying to connect my app to the database it is showing an error of cannot find symbol.

```
error: cannot find symbol
                String ownerName = ownerName.getEditText().getText().toString();
                                            ^
  symbol:   method getEditText()
  location: variable ownerName of type String
```

below is my code

```
public class merchantRegistrationForm extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    EditText ownerName, phoneNumber, emailId, password, cnfPassword;

    DatabaseReference databaseReference;
    FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    FirebaseDatabase rootNode;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_merchant_registration_form);

        ownerName = findViewById(R.id.ownerName);
        phoneNumber = findViewById(R.id.ownerPhoneNumber);
        emailId = findViewById(R.id.ownerEmailId);
        password =findViewById(R.id.password);
        cnfPassword =findViewById(R.id.confirmPassword);

        Button goNext;
        goNext = findViewById(R.id.nextToBusinessSelector);
        goNext.setOnClickListener(this);

        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("merchant Signup");

        goNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override


            public void onClick(View v) {
                rootNode = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
                databaseReference = rootNode.getReference();
                String ownerName = ownerName.getEditText().getText().toString();
                String phoneNumber = phoneNumber.getEditText().getText().toString();
                String emailId = emailId.getEditText().getText().toString();
                String password = password.getEditText().getText().toString();
                String cnfPassword = cnfPassword.getEditText().getText().toString();
                merchantsignup helperclass = new merchantsignup(ownerName, phoneNumber,emailId, password, cnfPassword);

                databaseReference.setValue("hello");

            }
        });


        Intent intent = new Intent(merchantRegistrationForm.this, salonDetails.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Few Steps more", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }



    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is confusing because you initially declare `ownerName` as an EditText:

```
EditText ownerName;
```

But then redefined it as a string:

```
String ownerName = ownerName.getEditText().getText().toString();
```

The error message is telling you that there is no method `getEditText()` on a String object.  Perhaps you want to use a different name for the string variable.